# How to test if method returns expected data type?

Tags: c#, nunit

Is it possible to create a NUnit Test method to check if the method returns the expected data type ?

Here's what I mean:

I've a static string that takes two parameters and checks to see if it matches with another string. If it does the methods simply returns that string.

I want to test to ensure that this method does infact return type of string and any exceptions that might occur.

Sample Code:

```
public static string GetXmlAttributeValue(this XmlElement element, string attributeName)
    {
        if (element == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
        }

        if (attributeName == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("attributeName");
        }

        string attributeValue = string.Empty;
        if (element.HasAttribute(attributeName))
            attributeValue = element.Attributes[attributeName].Value;
        else
            throw new XmlException(element.LocalName + " does not have an attribute called " + attributeName);
        return attributeValue;
    }
```

Here's how my solution is looking:

[image]

I'd like to write my test code within the `TestLibrary` class library.

Comment: Given this method, what are you trying to test? What problem you face or what exactly you don't know?

Comment: What I expect is for a `attributeValue` to be of type string. I want to test if the method does return that data type from my `TestClass.cs`. I should add that I've only started looking into N-Unit testing today.

Comment: If you declare a method's return type as `string`, C# compiler will make sure that the method can only return a valid `string` instance or `null`. Nothing else is possible. You don't have to test it, Typically you'll test what is the expected output when given some input.

Answer (score 13):

Normally, there is no need to test the return type. C# is statically typed language, so this method cannot return something else different than string.

But If you want to write a test, which will fail if someone changes the return type, you can do something like this:

```
Assert.That(result, Is.TypeOf<string>());
```

Answer (score 2):

To test for the return type you can use the `Is.TypeOf<yourType>` syntax mentioned by @dimitar-tsonev. [Here is a list](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=typeConstraints&r=2.6.4) of the supported type contraints:

You also mention that you want to write tests to verify the exceptions. For that you can either use the `ExpectedExceptionAttribute` attribute as [documented here](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=exception&r=2.6.4) or the exception asserts syntax as [documented here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=exceptionAsserts&r=2.6.4).

Answer (score -2):

You Don't Need To Test For the method to return a certain data type because it can only return the specific return type. You could run the method and use an Assert to check it isn't null, then you know the method has returned the correct type.

```
var result = GetXmlAttributeValue(par1,par2);

Assert.isNotNull(result);
```

Hope This helps!

Comment: What if the method under test is generic? What if we want to test that a derived type is returned?